# GRUB2 booting: efidisk read error & prefix is not set

Tags: linux, boot, grub, multi-boot, grub2

everyone!

I have a booting USB stick with some iso-image, based on Arch Linux. It loads through efi and then comes to Grub 1.99, where I can choose the iso images. I can load them without any problems, but before I see the menu of the Grub some error messages appear:

> error: "prefix" is not set
>
> error: efidisk read error

USB stick is formatted in FAT32 and has a partition table msdos.

Here is my /boot/grub/grub.cfg

> insmod video
>   insmod font
>   insmod jpeg
>
> insmod gfxterm
>
> set prefix=/boot/grub/grub.cfg
>
> loadfont /boot/grub/unicode.pf2
>
> set gfxmode=auto
>   terminal_output gfxterm
>
> background_image /boot/grub/background.jpg
>   set default=0
>
> set timeout=10
>
> set menu_color_normal=white/black  set
>   menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
>
> menuentry "image.iso" {
>   set isofile="/images/image.iso"
>      loopback
>   loop $isofile      set root=(loop)     linux /isolinux/vmlinuz
>   isofile=$isofile splash quiet      initrd /isolinux/initrd  }

These settings works without any problems. At least, I can see my background image and the styles has been changed.

I also checked from the Grub shell the parameters

> root=hd2,msdos1 //means that I have a correct path, otherwise actually it doesn't boot.

I tried different versions of this prefix
// /boot/grub/
// /boot/grub/grub.cfg
// /efi/boot/

I would be glad to hear what can be the problem:)

p.s. Was reading also that can be sth with GPT partition table, but in this case it doesn't boot with my computer.

Thanks for helping.